# Jquery validate block form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using asp.net mvc 3 with unobtrusive jquery validation. I have a form that is for a model that contains various required attributes and other data annotations.

I am submitting this form using jquery like so

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        

        var user = {
            UserName: $('#@(Html.IdFor(m => m.UserName))').val(),
            Password: $('#@(Html.IdFor(m => m.Password))').val(),
            RememberMe: $('#@(Html.IdFor(m => m.RememberMe))').val(),
            returnUrl: '@Request.Url.PathAndQuery'
        };

        $('#loginform').hide();
        $('#loading').show();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.returnUrl) {
                    window.location.href = data.returnUrl;
                } else {
                    $("#loginform").replaceWith(data);
                }

            },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("There was an error logging in :'" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loginform').show();
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    });
}); </script>
```

The problem is that the form is validated (and errors will be shown for required fields etc) and then the form will be submitted which is causing errors.

How do I modify the jquery so that it checks the form is valid before doing this submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a call to if ($('form').valid()) which return true/false if the form is valid